# How to exclude parent field that uses Select widget?

Tags: django, django-forms

I would like to exclude a particular field (`data_type` that uses Select widget) in the subclass that is defined in the parent form. I defined the classes like this:

```
class ParentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    data_type = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=ANNOTATION_TYPES))

    class Meta:
        model = Annotation
        fields = ('data_value','data_type','active','primary_source')                 
        exclude = ()


class DetailForm(ParentForm):

    class Meta(ParentForm.Meta):        
        exclude = ('data_type','primary_source')
```

This looks OK:

```
print DetailForm.Meta.exclude
('data_type', 'primary_source')
```

However when I print HTML I still see the field `data_type` in the `DetailForm` (and I don't see the other excluded field `primary_source`):

```
print DetailForm(None)
```

HTML:

```
<tr><th><label for="id_data_value">Data value:</label></th>..
<tr><th><label for="id_active">Active:</label></th>....
<tr><th><label for="id_data_type">Data type:</label></th><td>
<select name="data_type" id="id_data_type">
<option value="Comment1">Subcellular location</option>
<option value="Comment2">Function</option>
<option value="Comment3">Sequence caution</option>
</select></td></tr>
```

It looks there is a problem with the way the `data_type` is defined. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `data_type` is not a model field, that will not work. You need to remove the field in `__init__`:

```
class DetailForm(ParentForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DetailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        del self.fields['data_type']
```